# Getting an undefined response from a Google Sheets call?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var oauth_token = 'hidden_for_stack_overflow';

var the_sheet = '';

fs.readFile('usethesecreds.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);

    const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = JSON.parse(content).installed;
    const auth = new google.google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0])
    auth.setCredentials({ access_token: oauth_token })
    the_sheet = google.google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
  });



// Get cells
function get_cells_MainSheet(spreadsheetId, range) {

    var response = the_sheet.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        range: range
    })

    console.log(response.status)
    console.log(response.statusText)

}
```

All I'm getting from those two console.logs is "undefined".

The spreadsheetId is correct, range is 'A:P'...

I think my problem is that I'm storing the_sheet as a global variable. But I'm not sure what to do for an alternative.

Comment: Hi ! I am not sure that is the issue but for the sake of troubleshooting try changing it by the following : ```const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});``` as described in the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample) (and then of course change it accordingly when making the ```get``` request. Also, let's check if the issue is in ```get_cells_MainSheet``` : add the following logs: ```console.log(spreadsheetId,range);``` and at the end ```console.log(response);```.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf this is what I get from `console.log(response)`:

 Promise { <pending> }

Comment: What about ```console.log(spreadsheetId,range);``` ? Are you getting your expected values there?